# Как сделать так,чтобы бот анализировал конкретные каналы?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так,чтобы человек не мог отправить больше 1 сообщения в категорию из 3-х каналов.
Вот код:

```
nabor1_channel_id = 970768863622995968
nabor2_channel_id = 970768884858761247
nabor3_channel_id = 970768911941398579


nabor = [nabor1_channel_id,
nabor2_channel_id, nabor3_channel_id]


@bot.listen('on_message')
async def on_message_four(message):
    if message.channel.id in nabor:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            pass
        else:
            
            if len(message.content) > 1: # проблема в этой строчке
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"Не спамь!")
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `message.content` распространялся только на 3 выделенных мной канала?
Надеюсь,что вопрос вам понятен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.content` возвращает текст сообщения, а не количество отправленных сообщений с данным тексом. Вопрос немного непонятен, так что я отвечу сразу на несколько:

**1: Как сделать так, чтобы человек мог отправить только 1 сообщение в канал?**

```
ban_list = []
channels = []
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.channel.id in channels:
        if not message.author.bot:
             # Если уже было сообщение, у котороего channel == message.channel и author == message.author, то...
            if [x for x in ban_list if x["channel"] == message.channel and x["user"] == message.author]:
                await message.channel.send(f"Не спамь!", delete_after=5)
                await message.delete()
            else:
                # Если такого сообщения не было, то добавить новое сообщение в ban_list сообщений
                ban_list.append({"channel": message.channel, "user": message.author})
```

**2: Как сделать так, чтобы человек мог отправить только 1 сообщение с определённым текстом в канал?**

```
ban_list = []
channels = []
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.channel.id in channels:
        if not message.author.bot:
            # Если уже было сообщение, у котороего channel == message.channel, author == message.author и content == message.content, то...
            if [x for x in self.ban_list if x["channel"] == message.channel and x["user"] == message.author and x["content"] == message.content]:
                await message.channel.send(f"Не спамь!", delete_after=5)
                await message.delete()
            else:
                # Если такого сообщения не было, то добавить новое сообщение в ban_list сообщений
            self.ban_list.append({"channel": message.channel, "user": message.author, "content": message.content})
```

Comment: Приветствую!Проблема в том,что бот анализирует сообщения со всего сервера.То бишь,я хочу сделать так,чтобы в случае обнаружения сообщения в одном из трёх каналов, последующие удалялись.А мой код рассчитан на сообщения со всех каналов сервера.Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не понял. Нужно только с определённых каналов или со всего сервера? Если с определённых, то код в ответе, а есть со всего сервера, то уберите первое условие `if message.channel.id in channels:` и всё